# Getting dynamic URL's to work without adding pages to WordPress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, templates, redirect

I have this URL:

**example.com/parent/**

I have created this page in WordPress and it uses the template page-parent.php

Is there a way I can create pages dynamically under this that uses this template without adding a page to WordPress, I know I can do this with a query variable

e.g. `example.com/parent/?q=17`

but I want to know if I can have:

**example.com/parent/child1/**

**example.com/parent/child2/**

Without adding these as `'Pages'` and using the parent template.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [add_rewrite_rule | WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Comment: Thank you  @cabrerahector that's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: There's a chance that someone will stumble upon this question in the future so it'd be nice if you could share the solution you came up with (it's perfectly valid to answer your own question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @cabrerahector - I was looking for the [add_rewrite_rule()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) I just needed to add  these functions and refresh my permalinks.

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%child%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^parent/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=207&child=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sub-folder in your theme folder called 'page-templates'
2. Move the 'parent.php' code into that folder
3. Add this line to the top of the parent.php: `<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>` with whatever name you'd like to use.
4. You should be able to select that Template in the page editor while in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your page-parent.php is a template specific to that one page (due to the page slug matching the file name). You can however convert your existing page-parent.php file to be a template that can be used for any number of pages.

1. Rename your page-parent.php file to template-parent.php
2. Add this line to the top of the template-parent.php:  (replace "Parent Page" with whatever name you'd like to use for the template name).
3. In the WordPress admin, choose this new template for the "Parent" page and all other child pages you wish to use it for.